# Error after trying to access xml (Zlib::BufError) (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I keep getting and error whenever I try and access an XML file in Ruby. This is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'


url = 'http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls'
service = '/text/TextGetRankedTaxonomy'
apikey = '?apikey=4317fce9281094613deee9ebcc5aaf5238cd0748'
thething = '&text='
text = 'men%27s%20white%20crew%20neck%20shirt'

fullurl = url + service + apikey + thething + text 

opener  = open(fullurl) {|f| f.read }
```

Here is the error:

```
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:357:in `finish': buffer error (Zlib::BufError)
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:357:in `finish'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:262:in `ensure in inflater'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:262:in `inflater'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:274:in `read_body_0'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:201:in `read_body'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:226:in `body'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:163:in `reading_body'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1420:in `block in transport_request'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `transport_request'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:509:in `block in post_form'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:583:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:507:in `post_form'
    from C:/Users/KVadher/Desktop/test151:11:in `<main>'
```

Is there anything I can do to either solve the error or run past it?

Comment: Dude, the example shows just strings concatenation

Comment: My bad, I've added the line of code that's meant to show you all the details from the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the way this API server is encoding the data. To bypass this, you can simple say in the HTTP header that you don't accept any kind of encoding:

```
opener = open(fullurl, 'Accept-Encoding' => '') {|f| f.read }
```